# Associate cells to imported ones with IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have table A with several columns and I use the following function to import some of data to table B:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("0AuFgJ0VZkU8kdHdnU0N2Y3hFU3B6bkpjdEFsUEZOcXc"&"?"&now(),"A:BL"),"select Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col3, Col4, Col15, Col16, Col17, Col18 where Col52 contains 'X'",1)
```

After that, I have several columns where I need to enter new data: from N to R for example. Let's say that when function is accomplished in table B I have three rows:

```
A1: Ana
A2: Jacques
A3: Peter
```

In N2 I put something, for example `French`. If in table A I delete `Ana`, it is deleted in table B and A1 is `Jacques` and A2 is `Peter`. But `French` is still in N2, so now it is like `Peter` is English.

How to make N2 (`French`) to be associated with A2 (`Jacques`) so if `Jacques` moves to A1, `French` moves to N1 too?

Extra information posted by OP as 'Answer':

> I need to keep the link with the source table because I need to add or remove records. So, Paste values only will not help. My source table is very bi, so I need in fact to extract some records and add new data on them. It is not really nationality, I just gave an example, but multiple columns. I mean that from one very big database I need to extract only those records that I need by putting `X` on a specific column and after that to work in another table only with the extracted ones.

Comment: It is a little hard to read what your problem is. If you could share a spreadsheet with us, it would be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two choices that would not suit you:

1)  Put `French` into wherever you are importing from.
2)  Once the range is imported, break the link (Copy, Paste special, Paste values only) so that deleting `Ana` in the source no longer causes her to disappear from the imported data.

Both the above can be avoided with a lookup table but to do so would be ‘ugly’ and if imported data is added to, rather than have parts deleted from it, could require a tedious amount of repetition. However it might be acceptable as a workaround.

Import to two different ranges and Copy, Paste special, Paste values only one of those. Add `French` to the converted version (the one no longer linked) and use that as a lookup table to place `French` where you would like, by searching for `Jacques` (and `Ana` and `Peter`) by cell reference from the linked version.

Comment: I need to keep the link with the source table because I need to add or remove records. So, Paste values only will not help. My source table is very bi, so I need in fact to extract some records and add neew data on them. It is not really nationality, I just gave an exemple, but multiple columns. I mean that from one very big database I need to extract only those records that I need my putting X on a specific column and after that to work in another table only with the extracted ones.